# нужно каждый час запускать Electron АПКУ на windows

Tags: javascript, windows, cron, electron, crontab

всем привет!
ситуация следующая - мне нужно каждый час запускать **exe-файл** или скрипт **main.js** в виндовс 7,8,10. Апка на ***Electron***, делает запрос на сервер и показывает сообщение с БД.

---

То есть я могу запускать или скрипт (типа **npm start**) или сразу exe (Electron имеет библиотеку, которая делает исполняемые файлы для всех ОС). Подскажите возможно какой планировщик ли еще что-то, чтобы раз в час запускать это дело.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартным виндовым планировщиком можно запускать exe с аргументами. Время тоже любое можно поставить.